# How to grant access to a share to Local System

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a program that runs as a service under the "Local System" account on a Windows Server 2008. This program needs to move files out of a share. This share is on the same server as the service.

How can I grant access to this share for the service? I tried adding the servername in the permissions tab of the share. That didn't work though.

Of course the program could use the local path to the files but it only knows the path to the share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch the location (Permissions -> Locations) from the domain tree to the server name and then search for "SYSTEM". After adding this account to the permissions it worked.